# Bundles within a Bundle

Tags: java, client-server, osgi

I'm trying to implement a client-sever model using OSGi. the server application is the OSGi framework that is running in a computer and client applications connect to its console remotely and send their commands via a Java Socket and receive their proper responses. Each client application consists of several modules. Now I have two approaches:

1- Each module could be a bundle that is installed on the framework and client applications receive services from them. However this solution has a problem. If I wanted each client to have a special update method (e.g. Bundle A should be updated in some of them but in others it should not be updated), how can I manage this type of updates?

2- Each client application is be a bundle of bundles. Now my concern is that how can I manage the update action in a way that when I update the client application it updates the inner bundles too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is decidedly generic and it is not possible to provide a detailed answer in a reasonable space and time. I will try to cover some ideas and suggestions though.

1. Updating distinct bundles on distinct clients is a non-issue. From the programmatic viewpoint, you have many choices (I would rather suggest you read [OSGi in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988916) for a tour of the facilities that OSGi frameworks adhering to the specification provide). I don't know if you intend to use Remote OSGI (as of Chapter 13 of the [Enterprise specification](http://www.osgi.org/download/r4v42/r4.enterprise.pdf)). Clearly, you want your client-server API bundles/services to be preserved. Other than that, an OSGi bundle can pick a bundle/service from whoever exposes it (more on that in OSGi in Action, again). Provisioning is another aspect: that depends on who (client or server) controls updating; on the simplest case, you just juggle bundles around manually and install/start/stop/uninstall them from the framework console.
2. Unless I am missing something from your description, you cannot choose this path since you cannot have a bundle of bundles. This concept simply does not exist in the bare OSGi specification. The bundle hierarchy is perfectly flat, therefore you cannot perform "physical hiding". To instead *logically* hide bundles behind other bundles, you must operate on the services they expose, but the burden is completely on you. You could do the same through packages, but I would not recommend that. That being said, I am not perfectly up-to-date with bleeding-edge Service Component Architecture (SCA) implementations such as [Tuscany](http://tuscany.apache.org/) release 2. That one **could** give you a hand since it promised to be OSGi aware. The [Tuscany SCA in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988894) book, while recent, covers release 1 only. A worthy read, but probably not what you are looking for. Wrapping up, you cannot *monolithically* update an OSGI application in the strict sense: you would have to specify each bundle to be updated. This must be seen as an advantage: you have more control on your application. The downside is clearly on the effort of managing the update at such finer granularity.

I hope this simplified discussion was of use to you.

Comment: The comment on Remote OSGi was related to how you would interface client and server. It does not specifically help you in providing additional levels of abstraction: it just allows you to extend the OSGi approach between separate JVM instances. Anyway, OSGi in Action does not cover Remote Services. I would suggest you have a look at   [Apache CXF DOSGi](http://cxf.apache.org/distributed-osgi.html), that has very minimal and clear examples.